# Session changes done in application_Error rolled back after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application and I am trying to handle custom exception using Application_Error. It works nicely but I have new requirement to set the error data in Session object(or any object that can maintain state) and redirect to Error.aspx page. THere I am just removing the error messages after reading them.

So, Whatever I add to session object(or if I change a previously existing value) in Application_error and when I call Redirect. In the error.aspx I don't see any of the value as if Session was in readonly mode in Application_error.

I tried by calling 
    session.IsReadOnly
to see if its read only. But it returns false!!

Comment: Not to worry, I've managed to resolve it and have added the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this problem myself and, after a couple of hours of messing around, managed to solve it.  The issue is that `Application_Error()` clears the session after executing as part of some sort of "cleanup" routine which you need to stop.

The solution I found is as follows:

1. Call `Server.ClearError();` - this clears the last error from the application and stops the "cleanup" taking place, thus preserving session.
2. The (unwanted imho) side-effect of this is that it no longer performs the automatic redirect to the error page, so you need to explicitly call `Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx");`

So, something like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Grab the last exception
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    // put it in session
    Session["Last_Exception"] = ex;

    // clear the last error to stop .net clearing session
    Server.ClearError();

    // The above stops the auto-redirect - so do a redirect!
    Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx");
}
```

If you don't want to hard-code the URL, you could grab the `defaultRedirect` URL directly from the `customerrors` section in the `web.config`, which would give you something like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Grab the last exception
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    // put it in session
    Session["Last_Exception"] = ex;

    // clear the last error to stop .net clearing session
    Server.ClearError();

    // The above stops the auto-redirect - so do a redirect using the default redirect from the customErrors section of the web.config!
    var customerrors = (CustomErrorsSection)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/").GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
    Response.Redirect(customerrors.DefaultRedirect);
}
```

Comment: That's a perfect solution! Worked like a charm and very well explained too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, the problem is with the redirect call.

[Don't redirect after setting a Session variable (or do it right)](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx)

Comment: I have seen this one. I am actually calling it with false without response.end().. Lemme post the code here..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Cache and an appropriate naming strategy for your key, like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["error:" + Session.SessionID] = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
    }
```

in the Error.aspx page you ca read it like this:

```
var error = Cache["error:" + Session.SessionID];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a directive to the **Global.asax** file, Imports the **System.Web** Namespace

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>


void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   string message = Server.GetLastError().Message;
   Session["error"] = message;
   Server.Transfer("Error.aspx");

}
```

Write the error message added in the sesion object in the **Error.aspx** page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
        Response.Write(Session["error"].ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might that the [AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx) event might not have fired when the exception was raised in your application, you will be able to set a session value only after this particular event is fired as this is the stage where the application state is set